# JavaScript in external file is executed before the script tag's onload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, loading, jquery-events

I've read that `defer` won't necessarily delay the loading of an external script, but it will [defer the execution of the script](https://bitsofco.de/async-vs-defer/) till after the HTML has been parsed.

[image]

As an experiment I add a line to the bottom of a file containing jQuery which emits an event when execution gets to the end of the JavaScript:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('jQuery-executed'));
```

I include the jQuery file in my test page with a `defer` attribute:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js" defer onload="console.log('jQuery loaded', Date.now());"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        console.log('DOMREADY', Date.now());
    });

    window.addEventListener('jQuery-executed', function(){
        console.log('jQuery executed', Date.now());
    });
</script>
```

I have an `onload` handler on the script tag to tell me when the file was loaded, and other functions output console logs on DOMContentLoaded and when the jQuery is executed.

Why when I view this page do I get this?

[image]

Surely things should happen in a different order? Shouldn't jQuery only be executed after the file containing it has loaded? And why's it being executed before DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: Check the W3C HTML5 spec. The "load" event fires *after* the script content runs, not before.

Comment: Also it makes sense for DOMContentLoaded to wait for scripts to load, since the code in a handler for it should properly expect all scripts to be present.

Comment: [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) *"... executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded."*

Comment: Ahh thanks guys, that clarifies it perfectly. Do you want to post an answer @Pointy? In case anybody else has trouble with the byzantine language of the W3C spec, the part Pointy seems to be talking about is https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script, where "fire an event named load at the script element" comes after "Run the classic script given by the script's script."

Comment: Interestingly when I use async instead of defer, I get logs in the order DOMREADY, jQuery executed, jQuery loaded. So async seems to remove the script from the DOMContentLoaded sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTML5 spec is weird and hard to read, but it does say that deferred script content should be evaluated before the "load" event is fired. If you think about it, that's really a good thing: if you have some code that's waiting for a script to load, it's *probably* because you want to *use* some code that the script provided. If the "load" event fired before the script ran, it would not really be useful to have a "load" handler.

Same goes for "DOMContentReady": code waiting for that event to fire properly expects that all the script content imported by the page is ready to be exploited.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks Pointy. This order of events is indeed very useful for me: it gives me the confidence that the JS in the file is available.